# Swift 2.0 error Downcast from '[NSIndexPath]?' to '[indexpath]' only unwraps optional

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

Hi below code was working fine in swift1.2 but when I upgraded to swift 2.0:

```
func deselectAllRows() {
    if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows as! [NSIndexPath] {
        for indexPath in selectedRows {
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

It shows the following error :

> Downcast from '[NSIndexPath]?' to '[indexpath]' only unwraps optional

Any clue on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to force a typecast anymore, `indexPathsForSelectedRows` returns the right type:

```
func deselectAllRows() {
    if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
        for indexPath in selectedRows {
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/indexPathsForSelectedRows) returns `[NSIndexPath]?`, so you don't need to type cast it. You can just write it like:

```
func deselectAllRows()
{
   if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
   {
      for indexPath in selectedRows
       {
           tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
        }
   }
}
```